# how to know when the password for monogdb database is going to expire?

Tags: mongodb

We are using mongodb , and i want to know when the password for my mongodb user expire , is their any way we can check the life time of the password .

Can you please anyone provide any query or command , that we can use to check the password life time for mongodb

Comment: What password are we talking about?

Comment: mongodb password , for a database their are user name and password will present , so i am taking abt that password

Comment: Why you think that this password would expire

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to username/password for [MongoDB Server Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/), currently there is no expiration time. There is an open tracking ticket [SERVER-3197](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3197) for a feature to expire passwords after a period of time. Feel free to upvote/watch the ticket for progress update on the ticket.

If you want database users to be able to change their own passwords a custom role needs to be created, see [Tutorial: Change Your Password And Custom Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-own-password-and-custom-data/)

Comment: note - they closed that issue stating "won't fix".  It's unfortunate.